# Excel VBA not showing userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro that opens by asking the user a series of questions (asking them to say which of the open workbooks performs which function).  I have a series of userform.show commands as below:

```
  UserForm2.Show  ' select cost data file
  Set piersBook = ActiveWorkbook

  UserForm5.Show  ' select IRR file
  Set irrBook = ActiveWorkbook

  UserForm6.Show  ' select BC summary file
  Set bcSummary = ActiveWorkbook
```

(now, after the event, I realise it would have been more simple to put these into one userform).

The net effect is for the last one not to display.
After some research I changed the code to:

```
  UserForm2.Show  ' select cost data file
  Set piersBook = ActiveWorkbook

  UserForm5.Show  ' select IRR file
  Set irrBook = ActiveWorkbook

  DoEvents

  UserForm6.Show  ' select BC summary file
  Set bcSummary = ActiveWorkbook
```

This worked for about 5 or 6 iterations, before it reverted to the original problem.

I put breakpoints in the userform initialize code.  They were all called and the userforms all worked (until I removed the breakpoints again).

Finally I started removing the offending userform: the problem transfered itself to the next one back.  And again, when that was removed, to the one before.

The userforms' code is identical:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
  Workbooks(ListBox1.Value).Activate
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim wb As Workbook
  For Each wb In Workbooks
    ListBox1.AddItem wb.Name
  Next wb
End Sub
```

Any thoughts?  At the moment I am hardcoding the inputs which is not ideal.
Many thanks.

Comment: Great - thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use only `UserForm2`, then:

- change your `UserForm2` code as follows

  ```
  Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
      With Me
          If ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
              .Tag = .ListBox1.Value
              .Hide
          Else
              MsgBox "You must select a workbook"
          End If
      End With
  End Sub

  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
      ListBox1.AddItem wb.Name
    Next wb
  End Sub
  ```
- change your "main" code as follows

  ```
  Dim piersBook As Workbook, irrBook As Workbook, bcSummary As Workbook

  With UserForm2
      .Caption = "select cost data file"
      .Show  ' select cost data file
      Set piersBook = Workbooks(.Tag)

      .Caption = "select IRR file"
      .Show  ' select cost data file
      Set irrBook = Workbooks(.Tag)

      .Caption = "select BC summary file"
      .Show  ' select BC summary file
      Set bcSummary = Workbooks(.Tag)
  End With
  Unload UserForm2
  ```